# TechniSat SkyStar USB 2

Tags: drivers, usb-installation, dvb

How can I use [TechniSat SkyStar USB 2](http://optishop.si/media/uploads/public/document/15-pp_pc_q3_10_exp_oa_view_sl.pdf) (external USB 2.0 satellite receiver for the reception of digital television and radio on a laptop or PC ) in Ubuntu 14.04?

[image]

Please help me step by step.

`lsusb` gives me this result:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d0:2282 Techsan Electronics Co., Ltd. TechniSat DVB-PC TV Star 2
```

`sudo dmesg` gives me these results:

```
[ 9232.032260] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 9232.124755] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=13d0, idProduct=2282
[ 9232.124766] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 9232.156955] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[ 9232.228429] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[ 9823.092911] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 9825.884199] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 9825.976692] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=13d0, idProduct=2282
[ 9825.976703] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Answer (score 2):

According to an entry in [ubuntuusers Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/DVB-Karten#TechniSat), there's a driver for TechniSat SkyStar USB in the Linux kernel since quite a while, but the firmware is missing, since it cannot be distributed with Linux for license reasons. From what I can see, you need to:

1. Install the firmware package:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree
   ```

   Since apparently, that is not enough, [download the firmware](http://kernellabs.com/firmware/technisat-usb2/) and place it in `/lib/firmware`:

   ```sh
   cd /lib/firmware
   sudo wget http://kernellabs.com/firmware/technisat-usb2/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw
   ```

   Additionally you need to enable the responsible kernel module:
2. Until the end of the current boot

   ```sh
   sudo modprobe dvb-usb-technisat-usb2
   ```
3. For future boots

   ```sh
   printf '# %s\n%s\n' 'TechniSat SkyStar USB 2' dvb-usb-technisat-usb2 | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/technisat-usb2.conf
   ```

You can use [MythTV](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mythtv/) to interact with your DVB receiver.